# Permission Exception when I use PowerManager.WakeLock with AlaramManager android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I am developing a native android app that run some operation every 30 mins.
I need to make sure that the processor is running, so I used

PowerManager.Wakelock inside the alarm receiver.

here is the code I am using inside for my alarm receiver.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
        wl.acquire();
        Intent eventService = new Intent(context, SyncInBackground.class);
        context.startService(eventService);
        wl.release();
    }
}
```

and In my main AndroidManifest.xml

I added the following line to request a permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.wake_lock"/>
```

When I run the alarm in my application I got the following exception

```
02-07 23:25:02.839  13699-13699/com.snappext E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.snappext.Backup.AlarmReceiver: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10008 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:127)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10008 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
            at android.os.IPowerManager$Stub$Proxy.acquireWakeLock(IPowerManager.java:381)
            at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquireLocked(PowerManager.java:297)
            at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire(PowerManager.java:276)
            at com.snappext.Backup.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:54)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2133)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:127)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any clue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android permissions are case sensitive. Use this instead:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the permission to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

I assume the uppercase letters make a difference here but I could be wrong.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html